# Flex URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have some code written by another person. It's uploading a file to a server. I want to post simillar request but without sending a file (my version will copy file of a given name). I can't use method file.Upload(...). So what function I can use?
This is a code of request with file:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ApiConfig.ApiUrl);
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            request.data = params;
            try
            {
                _fileRef.upload(request);
            }
            catch(error:Error)
            {
                Alert.show(error.message);
            }
```

I simply whant to make simillar request, but without uploading file and not using file instance. 
I think it's pretty much dumb question but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something very different than the original code.  You make requests to a server using HTTPRequest, WebService, or RemoteObject depending how your service is set up to accept requests.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was dumb question. I used URLLoader and it works great:)

Comment: Great!  I encourage you to answer your own question.